# how to use external product in In-App purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to show product list from my web service and need pay money using in-app purchases. Is it possible to pay money using IAP?

also I want to sale a same product for multiple time.

As far as I know IAP won't support this...

Can we use Apply Pay for this?

I need some suggestion regarding this, any suggestions Please...

Comment: Are you selling physical goods & services provided "in the real world" or virtual goods such content that will be consumed in-app like music or images, or features you enable in your app?

Comment: its virtual goods and content that will be consumed in-app... I want to get goods from my own service, I dont want to add in itunes connect

Comment: For virtual goods consumed in-app you must use iAP.  The iAP products must be in iTunes connect.  You can try creating "credit" consumable iAPs that can be redeemed for products from your server, but I have heard of apps that use this approach being rejected.